# Double tax rules in invoice

Tags: php, magento

Somehow we get double tax rules in the Orders.

For example this screenshot.

[image]

I'm little bit worried about the second line. I don't understand where it's coming from.

We have 5 storeviews with different tax rates and the setup is like this:
[image]

For each storeview we have only changed "Default Tax Destination Calculation". For example this store view we only changed the Default Country:
[image]

Is this a bug in Magento or are my settings wrong?

Thank you.
Gr,
Lex

Comment: Do you have some overwritten core classes?

Comment: This doesn't really feel on-topic on Stack Overflow. It is not a programming question.